# How to Compute the Reconstruction error in Principal Component Analysis at lower dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, pca, error, dimensionality-reduction, eigenvalues

I have m examples and d features where m<<d. So I managed to compute the eigen value and corresponding its eigen vector ... I want to compute the reconstruction error for various value of principal components  , lets say n principal componets (n eigen vector corresponsing to first max n eigen values)

So My original dataset has shape

```
(m, d)
```

If I take n principle components where n < d, the transformed matrix matrix would have shape

```
(m, n)
```

So Since the shapes mismatch I really wasnt able to find any way to compute the reconstruction error

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you cannot compute the error in that fashion because the dimensional space is not the same, you would need first to 'reconstruct' your **new-reduced** space to the **old-bigger** dimensional space and there you can compute the error as you said.

For the *dimensionality reduction* we do:

$T = XP$

for the *reconstruction* we do:

$\hat{X} = TP^{'}$

where $X$ is the original data, $T$ is the reduced space (formally called scores), $P$ are the loadings (PCs) and $\hat{X}$ is the **reconstructed** space.

Finally, we commonly express the error as:

$Error = (X - \hat{X})^{2}$

---

**Edit:**

How do we interpret *Error*:

Before, first we denoted $X$ as our matrix of original data $\mathbb{R}^{nxk}$ *($n$ data points with $k$ dimensions each*), and then we moved to the reduced space $\hat{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{nxp}: p<k$

When we compute the error, we are computing the distance (norm) between the original ($p$ dimensional) and the proyected ($k$ dimensional) observation.

Comment: $X$ and $\hat{X}$ are both matrices. What operation do you mean when you write $(X-\hat{X})^2$? Perhaps you're referring to some type of matrix norm?

Comment: Yes!, I edited my answer

Comment: Specifically you want either the Frobenius norm $||\cdot||_F$ or (less likely but still correct) the spectral norm $||\cdot||_2$. Either will do here; see http://people.tamu.edu/~sji/classes/PCA.pdf.