# PCA as minimization of the reconstruction error

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

I've found the following definition of $PCA$ and I was trying to better understand it.

Having a dataset $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ we approximate it as $X \sim V^TA$ by minimizing the loss w.r.t the following constraints:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{l}_{PCA}(X; A,&V) := \|X - V^TA\|^2_F\\
&s.t. \, \, A \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{l} \times m} \, , \, V \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{l} \times d} \, , \,VV^T= I_{\mathcal{l}}
\end{align}

Now I'm actually trying to better understand what the matrices $A$ and $V$ actually represent. I guess that the matrix $V$ is nothing but the *orthogonal* matrix made up of the *eigenvectors basis* and $A$ should be the matrix of the coefficients obtained by **projecting** the original data contained in $X$ on the subspace spanned by the columns of $V$.

I still have some troubles trying to expand the above formula in a mathematical form:

\begin{align}
\|X - V^TA\|^2_F &= \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^m |x_{ij} - (V^TA)_{ij}|^2 \\
     & =  \, \, \, \, \, ?
\end{align}

Should I write the matrix $V^TA$ as some outer product?

I always get stuck when it comes to Matrix algebra notation ...

Comment: Does this help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194278/meaning-of-reconstruction-error-in-pca-and-lda, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492953/how-to-compute-the-reconstruction-error-in-principal-component-analysis-at-lower, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486959/does-pcas-reconstruction-error-get-reduced-with-more-pcs-being-used